# How to show raw queries(CQL) in Scylla/Cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, scylla

I am using Scylla(Cassandra's drop in replacement) db in docker container. I am using Python driver to connect with Scylla db for querying. I need to know the exact CQL query is applying on the database engine.

So, if there any way to print the query on the console(docker logs) or somewhere I can see and copy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use tracing to ask the database to store the queries in a table. Be careful as there is a large performance impact.

Comment: How can I ask the database? Any example?

Comment: It depends on the driver. For the Python driver, use the [trace parameter](https://python-driver.docs.scylladb.com/stable/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute_async). to `execute` or `execute_async`.